# How to setup TFS 2018 to pull source from Git over SSH?

Tags: git, ssh, tfs

I am setting up a continuous deployment server using TFS 2018 on-premise. The source code for the project is hosted on another Git server accessible over SSH or HTTPS. I am intending to use TFS only for the automation of new builds/deployments using TFS's Git polling.

I have two agents, one on Windows and one on Linux. The Linux agent is running as a Docker container. I'm using the Windows agent to build ASP.NET code, and it works fine using HTTPS authentication. I'm now trying to setup a build for the Linux agent that gets JavaScript code and builds it. The problem is that the Linux agent is unable to get the code.

- When trying HTTPS using exactly the same credentials that the Windows agent works with, I get "authentication failed":

  ```
  2018-12-19T15:43:57.0878068Z ##[command]git fetch --tags --prune --progress --no-recurse-submodules origin
  2018-12-19T15:43:57.0883732Z fatal: Authentication failed for 'https://***:***@<redacted>/'
  2018-12-19T15:43:57.0936665Z ##[warning]Git fetch failed with exit code 128, back off 2.956 seconds before retry.
  ```
- I decided to try using SSH to get the sources. I generated an SSH private/public key pair and added the public key to my account in the remote Git server. However, I can't configure the TFS Git "get sources" task to use SSH using private key authentication. There is no option in the Git service configuration for this, only to provide a user/password pair. Trying to simply paste the private key in the password box gives this:

  ```
  2018-12-19T15:49:46.2303693Z ##[command]git remote set-url origin ssh://emptyusername:***@<redacted>
  2018-12-19T15:49:46.2312696Z ##[command]git remote set-url --push origin ssh://emptyusername:***@<redacted>
  2018-12-19T15:49:46.2315992Z ##[command]git fetch --tags --prune --progress --no-recurse-submodules origin
  2018-12-19T15:49:46.2318791Z ssh: Could not resolve hostname emptyusername:-----begin rsa private key----- miieowibaakcaqeav7dgukagzcpr: Name or service not known
  2018-12-19T15:49:46.2319131Z fatal: Could not read from remote repository.
  ```
- Creating an SSH service in the Service manager in TFS doesn't work, as I believe that is for running remote commands over SSH, not for getting source code. (A service added this way does not show up at all in the build configuration, so it can't be selected.)
- I found documentation indicating you can use a PAT (personal access token) as the username for an HTTPS query. So I tried it, but got the same result as I got when trying to use my actual credentials:

  ```
  2018-12-19T15:57:45.3279943Z ##[command]git fetch --tags --prune --progress --no-recurse-submodules origin
  2018-12-19T15:57:45.3281813Z fatal: Authentication failed for 'https://voy2wog...@<redacted>'
  2018-12-19T15:57:45.3341431Z ##[warning]Git fetch failed with exit code 128, back off 4.71 seconds before retry.
  ```

So, to summarize:

- HTTPS authentication to the main Git server from a Windows agent works fine.
- HTTPS authentication to Git from a Linux agent always seems to fail.
- SSH authentication to Git is either not possible or is not obvious how to configure in TFS.

How can I resolve either one of these above two problems so that I can setup my continuous build?

I do need to be pulling directly from the Git repository, so that I can use the polling function to automatically build whenever a push is made to given branches. In other words, packaging the sources and feeding them to TFS in some other fashion is not appropriate.

I am trying to add the necessary tooling to my Windows agent for now, but I would like to deploy more agents ultimately, and Linux agents would be preferable, especially as we start moving to .NET Core and don't have to depend on Windows for builds. (Windows licensing costs and all)